# i am getting this error Invalid parameter value for approval_prompt: 'auto'' is not valid

Tags: php, google-signin

this is the error i am getting

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for approval_prompt: 'auto'' is not valid
```

Request Details

```
response_type=code
access_type=offline
client_id=xyz-
xyx.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=http://localhost/xyz/init/googleCallBack.php
state=scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
approval_prompt=auto'
```

here is the config for google login

```
$gClient= new Google_Client();
$gClient->setAuthConfig('init/client_secret.json');

$gClient->setApprovalPrompt('consent');
$gClient->setApplicationName('abc');
$gClient->setAccessType('offline');
$gClient>setRedirectUri('http://localhost/xyz/init/googleCallBack.php';
$gClient->setScopes(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);
```

i tried setting up approval_prompt or prompt both but it isn't working if i leave these two unset still i get invalid parameter 'prompt=auto'

Comment: Is there a typo for `approval_prompt`? Should be `auto` instead of `auto'`? Not sure if you've just made a typo mistake during formatting or just missed that.

Answer (score 3):

It is a mistake in [official web](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). You need set:

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setPrompt('consent');
```

Via merged pull-request in documentation https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/pull/1796